# 400 (Bad Request) ERROR while trying to use JS files in Content Editor Web Part

Tags: javascript, content-editor-web-part, http-400-bad-request

So, I added some code in Content Editor Web Part and code is started like this:

```
<script src="/<MyURL>/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/<MyURL>/_layouts/15/SP.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/<MyURL>/SiteAssets/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/<MyURL>/SiteAssets/knockout-3.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/<MyURL>/SiteAssets/Script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

For all these files I get a similar error for each in Chrome console:

```
GET http://MyURL/%3CSiteURL%3E/SiteAssets/knockout-3.0.0.js 400 (Bad Request)
```

...

I googled but the this error pops up so often for various situations that couldn't find answer for me and SharePoint. Any ideas?

Comment: Why Content Editor? Use Script Editor.
If you remove the Knockout line doest it work?

Comment: I use Content Editor then I use a script editor in it. About an error, I get the same error for each file.

Comment: Try to add a script editor and remove <MyURL> use this source src="/_layouts/15/script.js"

Comment: Done it. Those errors are gone but now the table that my code was supposed to create with information is gone(previously it showed table but with no info) and I get new error like:
Uncaught ReferenceError: /// args is not defined Script.js:61 ///
my.vm.RetrieveItemsFail Script.js:61 ///
(anonymous function) ScriptResource.axd?d=7bHa5m1dromXowi_eKldYsSiVPVUf6sqCQuHirM_ocGiCS3HymjC2gXwHY0NrucbnjCzbrk7XhxT76…:5 ///
SP.ClientRequest.$h_0 SP.Runtime.js:2 ///
SP.ClientRequest.$32_0 SP.Runtime.js:2

Comment: that on is a js error, to begin try to import just simple js file and see that they re working fine.

Comment: In JS, what are you doing?? Can you please show code.. I think this error occurs from the code not from you are importing JS files..  one more thing if you are passing full url as <MyURL> starting with http then remove / before <MyURL>..

Answer (score 1):

*This answer is community wiki. Feel free to improve.*

The URI path component cannot contain angle brackets (`< >`), that are encoded as `%3C` and `%3E` in your Bad Request. Other offending characters in URL components may include but aren't limited to commas `,`, question marks `?`, asterisks `*`, colons `:`, ampersands `&`, etc.

In the HTML placed in Content Editor or Script Web Parts you can use server relative URLs for scripts such as `/sites/team/_layouts/mySolution/myScript.js` or page relative such as `FolderInTheSamePagesLibrary/mySolution/myScript.js`. When necessary, you can reference external scripts using the full absolute URL such as `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js` (note that the protocol schema http/https is omitted to support script placement on both secured and unsecured pages).

ASP.NET controls for Script Registration also provide you with replaceable tokens such as `~site` and `~siteCollection` but these can only be used in server-side page code: master pages, page layouts, user controls and ASPX pages.